# How could I make logarithmic bins between 0 and 1?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to bin my data logarithmically while they are distributed between zero and one. I use this command :

```
nstep=10
loglvl=np.logspace(np.log10(0.0),np.log10(1.0),nstep)
```

but it doesn't work. any idea how it can be done in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
np.logspace(0.0, 1.0, nstep) / 10.
```

Comment: This doesn't start from zero. It starts from `log10(0)/10`, which is `0.1`.

Comment: `(np.logspace(0, 1.041392685158225, nstep) - 1) / 10` - Happy now?

Comment: Because you substract a constant, now spacing between bins is no more logarthmic. See that given `a = (np.logspace(0, 1.041392685158225, nstep) - 1) / 10`;  one finds that `a[1:]/a[:-1]` doesn't output an array with all same values (except the first).

Comment: Then just pass a negative start and have it *arbitrarily* close to 0. In the end, this is a log scale.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to choose a low "second number", then compute logarithmic-spaced values from this number to 1.0, and finally add zero at the beginning.

For example, setting 1.0e-8 as the second number in our sequence:

```
nstep = 10
seq = np.logspace(-8.0, 0.0, nstep)
np.insert(seq, 0, 0.0)
```

Which produces:

```
array([0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e-08, 7.74263683e-08, 5.99484250e-07,
   4.64158883e-06, 3.59381366e-05, 2.78255940e-04, 2.15443469e-03,
   1.66810054e-02, 1.29154967e-01, 1.00000000e+00])
```